# Why do we need the NaN value when we can throw TypeErrors?

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic, typeerror, nan

Why do programming languages have a `NaN` value?

```
Math.floor('string');  //--> NaN
```

Why not just throw a TypeError?

```
TypeError: Expected number instead of string
```

The question is tagged both [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) because JavaScript is the language I am primarily familiar with, but I know this applies to other languages as well.

Comment: Because exceptions are a pain in the neck :)

Comment: @Pointy Catching them doesn't seem to be so hard.

Comment: They introduce a sort of non-linearity in code. It's not so much that it's *hard*, it's just distracting and messy.

Comment: arguably, weak type languages should not throw from the core as a  result of mere type mismatches...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In typed languages, you must put a number in a number variable, even when you don't have a number. You put [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (that's why `typeof NaN` is `"number"` in JavaScript). That's just like `null` for object references when you don't have better.

And exceptions, which break the flow of instructions, really aren't so popular for everybody. Some might argue that they should be used for exceptionnal cases, not the simple fact that a string isn't parsable as a number.

Note that `NaN` can also be the result of a mathematical operation, occuring when it's not possible to decide what should be the result (for example `0 * Infinity`). It's simpler to handle this with NaN than to include branching in all operations.

Comment: Thanks! You make an interesting analogy `NaN : number :: null : object`

Comment: @Web_Designer Note that `typeof null` is `"object"` :)

Answer (score 4):

To be uncreative, it's because `NaN`s (as well as other non-numeric quantities, like infinity) are part of the [IEEE 754 floating-point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which many programming languages implement.

It's designed to allow for "special cases" in numeric computation to be evaluated like normal numbers without interrupting the calculations. That means no exceptions. In lieu of that, NaNs are generally propagated through operations until they come out on the other side, for better or worse.

Comment: yes, though in this particular case it's a *little* questionable to return `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

JavasScript is a weakly typed language.  Error throwing is expensive.  Look through jquery or underscore and you will see that errors are rarely thrown, only for "exceptional" cases.    It is less costly and easier to deal with values such as `NaN`.